# Load Data into Tridion 2011 from XML in Java

Tags: 2011, core-service

Am newbie to Tridion, I would like to parse an XML file and load its content into SDL Tridion 2011. can some help me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming from your question that your 'source' data is in separate XML files (or a large XML document) and you want to parse these (this) using Java and create new Components in Tridion with this content.

If this is the case, then there are lots of [tutorials online](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=strict&q=parse%20xml%20using%20java%20tutorial) for parsing the XML.

With regards to creating the new Components, you will want to use the Core Service. This is a Web service that allows applications to interact with the Content Manager. You can get started with this by checking out the [Interacting with the Core Service from Java](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-B2C3F336-0051-4576-8FFB-06A068CAA31F) section of the online documentation.

You may also want to consider using Mihai's [Core Service Java Client](http://mihaiconsulting.com/projects/core-service-java).

This should give you a good start.

Answer (score 3):

Tridion uses structure of schema, which is nothing but actual xsd schema.

The import process can be divided into following steps:

> 1. Based on xml file structure, create single or multiple schema (xsd). This can be manual step to create schema.
> 2. Create component based on schema defined in step 1 and update the component content from xml file using core service.